# MySQL cant start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I moved xampp installation from `C:\` to `F:\` and now it can't start saying:

```
> 2015-03-27 20:48:20 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2015-03-27 20:48:20 1608 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile 'C:\xampp\mysql\share\er
rmsg.sys'
2015-03-27 20:48:20 1608 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\xampp\mysql\data\x.lower-test
2015-03-27 20:48:20 1608 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\xampp\mysql\data\xe.lower-test
mysql\bin\mysqld: Can't change dir to 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 2 - No su
ch file or directory)
2015-03-27 20:48:20 1608 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What can I do? If I have to reinstall, how do I save my current database?

Comment: Did you change your data directory and config file?

Comment: Well, either correct all mentionings of paths in all files or reinstall. Or use an operating system with a working package management.

Comment: No, how can I do that? I only moved C:\xampp\ to F:\xampp\

Comment: If I simply reinstall, how can I backup my mysql database?

Comment: Move it back to the old place, start up, dump all data into files and that's it. After the reinstall you can load in the data again. Easiest is to use something like `mysqldump`

Comment: actually a snapshot takes significantly less time to restore than from a dump...

Comment: I've kinda screwed up somehow. Isn't it possible to just salvage the files from the data/databasename/ folder? all the table files are there, but I tried placing them in the new install data directory but didn't do anything.

Comment: you will need the ibdata1 file as well...that has all the metadata from your databases...